# I want to use a method from another class in flutter but it shown up error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build an suggestion image widget and I want to use the function that is already implemented in another file but I tried many ways it just won't work.
Here is the code I want to use in another file

```
void setupAutoImage() {
if (_loaded) {
  return;
}
//
if (widget.autoImage && mounted) {
  _loaded = true;
  widget.autoTextListner?.addListener(() {
    if (widget.autoTextListner?.hasPicture ?? false) {
      return;
    }
    autoImage(widget.autoTextListner?.text ?? '');
  });
}

Widget _widgetAutoImage() {
if (!widget.autoImage || _imagePreview.isEmpty || _image.isNotEmpty) {
  return const SizedBox();
}
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  width: widget.width,
  height: widget.width / 2,
  margin: widget.margin,
  child: CarouselSlider(
    options: CarouselOptions(
      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
      viewportFraction: .3,
      aspectRatio: 5,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
      initialPage: 1,
    ),
    //! loop data image from autoImage.
    items: _imagePreview.asMap().entries.map((item) {
      return Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _goCrop(item.key);
            },
            //! show image.
            child: Image.network(
              item.value,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              scale: 100.0,
              //! show loading until the image is displayed.
              loadingBuilder: (
                context,
                child,
                loadingProgress,
              ) {
                return _widgetImageLoading(loadingProgress, child);
              },
              //! show error if load image not working.
              errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => Center(
                child: Text(
                  AppLocalization.of(context)?.errorLoading ?? '',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

}

Here is the destination I want to use it at.

```
Widget _widgetSuggestion(){
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Container(
  width: width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
  child: **ImageContainer.setupAutoImage**,
);}
```

ImageContainer is showing up error says that I don't have the method setupAutoImage in the original file.
I already import the setupAutoImage file in the destination file I want to use, but I still wasn't able to use the method.

If it's able to run correctly, it would show up a list of suggestion image for user to choose from.

Comment: Apart from not beeing able to call the method, it also returns `void`, so using that as a child will fail, even if you succeed in your task at hand. Maybe post an [mcve] and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a function that returns a Widget, but you should expose a Widget itself. if any setting up needs to be done - use constructor or initState in case of the stateful widget.

Comment: as  i see `setupAutoImage()`have return type void it should return widget  . make function static so you can access using class name  and return type widget.  then it will be work.